# Access VBA To Rename First 3 Fields In A Table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Due to inconsistencies in an import process and people not following protocol, naming conventions between multiple tables that hold the same data are incorrect.  I am in need of a way to query all tables in a database, and if the first three fields are not named

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_address
```

Then rename the field to the naming convention above.  How can this be achieved using VBA Access 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will rename the first 3 fields in all non-system tables, but you should perhaps be a bit more careful about renaming fields in **all** tables. It *does* test to see if there are at least 3 fields in the table, but it doesn't currently add any fields if there are less than 3 fields.

```
Sub Rename()

  Dim db As Database
  Set db = CurrentDb()

  Dim tdf As TableDef
  For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    'Skip the system tables
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then

      Dim requiredNames() As Variant
      requiredNames = Array("emp_id", "emp_name", "emp_address")

      With tdf.Fields
        Dim fieldCounter
        For fieldCounter = LBound(requiredNames) To UBound(requiredNames)
          'Check the table has as many fields as we expect
          If fieldCounter < .Count Then
            'Check the field name isn't already the name we require
            If .Item(fieldCounter).Name <> requiredNames(fieldCounter) Then
              .Item(fieldCounter).Name = requiredNames(fieldCounter)
            End If
          End If
        Next fieldCounter
      End With
    End If
  Next tdf
End Sub
```